# Does console.log only execute when you use inspect on website?

Tags: javascript, console, console.log, userscripts

I have a lot of console.log in my script, and I don't want them slowing my script down when I don't have the console open.

So my question is, do they execute when the console is closed? Because if they do I would have to comment them out, and then uncomment them every time I need to see them.

Comment: Different browsers are different, but Firefox and Chrome definitely obey `console.log()` calls when the console is not visible.

Comment: @Pointy That unfortunate. So I would have to comment them out when I'm not using them to make my script run faster?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `console.log()` in your code will execute without the console open on the web page.

Answer (score 0):

In all the browsers I know of, they do execute even while the console is closed - for example, try running the following code with the console closed, then open the console after 5 seconds, and you'll see that the console has indeed been populated with the text:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  console.log('log');
}, 1000);
```

The performance impact of `console.log` is next to nothing, but if you wanted an easy way to toggle between having `console.log` calls print to the console, and do nothing, you can define a `console` variable on the top level of your userscript that has a `log` function which does nothing, thus *shadowing* `window.console.log` inside the scope of your userscript:

```js
const console = { log: () => void 0 };

console.log('foo');
```

To print to the console normally again, just comment out the `const console...` line (or use a boolean variable `doPrintToConsole` or something).

This will not prevent native page scripts from `console.log`ging. (If you wanted to prevent native page scripts from doing so, overwrite `window.console.log` instead);